# pyodbc parameterised sql result count distinct incorrect

Tags: sql-server, parameters, pyodbc

I am running a distinct count on a `sql server` table using `pyodbc`. When I run the query in `sql server` natively, I get different results.

```
columns = ['A','B','C']

for col in columns: 
    cursor.execute("select count(distinct(?)) from table",col)
    print (col)
    b = cursor.fetchone()
    distinctcount = b[0]
    print ('distinctcount %s '% distinctcount)
```

The output gives all columns as '1' when the real values should be 151988 for all columns.

```
A
distinctcount 1 
B
distinctcount 1
```

If I run a simple select count (*), then the result is consistent with the result in `sql server`.

```
for col in columns: 
    cursor.execute("select count(?) from table" , col)
    print (col)
    a = cursor.fetchone()
    rowcount = a[0]
    print ('rowcount %s '% rowcount)
```

result:

```
A
rowcount 151988 
B
rowcount 151988
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter substitution cannot be used to specify column (or table) *names*, only column *values*. You are executing a query that is essentially

```sql
select count(distinct('A')) from table
```

and that is returning `1` because the literal value `'A'` is the same for all rows so there is only one distinct value.

To specify a column *name* you need to use dynamic SQL, e.g.,

```python
sql = "select count(distinct([{}])) from table".format(col)
cursor.execute(sql)
```